# Можно ли импортировать переменные в LESS из JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, адаптивная-верстка, less

Вопрос чётко понятен из заголовка; чтобы не оставлять поле текста вопроса пустым, скажу, зачем мне это нужно. Нужно это затем, чтобы одни и те же переменные были доступны как в `JavaScript`, так и в `LESS` (следовательно, в `CSS`).

Подход такой может быть применим, например, при кроссплатформенной вёрстке, когда Вы не только меняете стиль через медиазапросы `CSS`, но и меняете вёрстку в целом, манипулируя `DOM` через `JS`; в этом случае удобно настроить минимальные и максимальные значения фаз (диапазонов ширины окна, при которых вёрстка не меняется) в файле `JSON`, который будет читаться как `LESS` для формирования для медиазапросов, так и `JS`. Т. о. `JSON` будет играть роль конфигурационного файла.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы и в браузере работало?

Comment: В смысле чтобы LESS брал переменные из JSON при загрузке страницы? Нет, LESS использую только при разработке сайта, а готовый сайт использует только CSS.

Comment: Наверняка к вашей системе сборки есть соответствующий плагин. Например для `gulp`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less-json-variables